# Where do I get XHProfLive for XHProf?

Tags: facebook, xhprof

I've read a long page about XHProfLive, but I didn't manage to find where to download it. Where do I find it?

http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=62667953919

I am aware that XHProf comes with some UI, but I didn't find anything more advanced than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been more than a year since I've asked the original question. There hasn't been much of an improvement to the original UI ever since. Therefore, I've undertaken the development of [xhprof.io](https://github.com/gajus/xhprof.io) - GUI to analyze the profiling data collected using XHProf.

Furthermore, as @gazarsgo have already mentioned, there is [Reinheimer's branch of the original XHProf UI](https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof).

Comment: The domain is up. In case this would happen ever again in future, you will always be able to find it at https://github.com/gajus/xhprof.io.

Answer (score 3):

XHProf was open sourced, not XHProfLive.

But do look into XHGui: http://phpadvent.org/2010/profiling-with-xhgui-by-paul-reinheimer